Primeros pasos en java
Estoy empezando en programación con Java y tengo mi primer error y duda.
Este es el código básico con el que estoy empezando para aprender operadores.
public class Declaraciones_Operadores {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Byte a=5;
        
        Byte b=7; 
        
        int c=b+a;
        
        c+=10;
        
        System.out.println(c);
        
    }

}

Hasta aqui todo bien. El error me salta cuando declaro como byte el valor c y no como int.
Hasta donde tengo entendido el valor de c es lo suficientemente pequeño como para poder declararlo como byte, pero si yo declaro byte c=a+b me salta el error.
Me gustaría que me pudieran aclarar porque no puedo declararlo como byte si así se supone que optimizaría espacio.
Gracias

puedes hacerlo asi:
Byte c = (byte) (b + a);

esto le indica que se quiere hacer un cast a bytes del resultado (b+a)
motivo:
La suma de dos valores de tipo Byte (b + a) no da como resultado un valor de tipo Byte. En Java, cuando se realizan operaciones aritméticas con tipos primitivos como Byte, Short o Char, estos pasan automáticamente al tipo int antes de realizar la operación. El resultado de b + a será de tipo int.
en el caso de c+= se hace una conversion implicita

Muchas gracias por la aclaracion.

Curiosamente, en C++ sucede lo mismo.
